# GCP: dispatch.yaml route limit

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform

We are using a GCP environment to setup our project. In that we require the use of dispatch.yaml file.

We want to redirect to the different server URL without changing the domain name in the browser. Dispatch.yaml fulfills this need but it allows only 20 routing rules.

How can we overcome this limitation of Dispatch.yaml? As we require more than 20 routing rules.

Answer (score 2):

Per [this Google Groups discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/vNSqsLmmvzM) it seems like this limit is a hard limit unlikely to change, GCP support said that:

> With more dispatch rules comes more CPU and memory resource requirements per app. [...].
>
> Ideally it is recommended to design your application to abide by App Engine quotas as they are set to protect the overall underlying architecture. Treating other micro-services as backend services and directly routing requests to them using their full target address via your main frontend default service is the recommended approach. This way you only have to maintain the URL requests to your main frontend client-facing default service, and not every service.

It seems like the request of a quota increase was denied for the user in the Group's discussion and they figured out a solution using Google Cloud Endpoints and the direct module/service addressing scheme in GAE.

The discussion is relatively old, but I believe that they won't change the limit. Nevertheless I would recommend [contacting the GCP support](https://cloud.google.com/support/) and explain your current situation so they can recommend the proper way for your app to avoid the limit.

There's also the possibility of a [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) to increase the limit. There's [already one created for this](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/117266829), you can reply in the post stating that you would also like the limit increased, so the GCP engineers know that more users are being affected by the limit.

Comment: Limit is clear in [the doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/reference/dispatch-yaml#limits). ESP is the best alternative. Personally, I didn't expect any change on this. AppEngine embedded services are piece by piece extracted and proposed for all GCP service and not only for AppEngine. In addition, I'm in an alpha program which could replace this -> Expecting a beta service for the next Google Cloud Next in April is the best side.